# Using GPS Satelites as dark matter detectors

Tags: dark-matter, experimental-technique

Recently, two scientists have proposed a new way of detecting dark matter, using GPS Satellites.
A part of the article is posted online: [Hunting for topological dark matter with atomic clocks.](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nphys3137.html)

Can anyone make the it more explicit? How exactly could GPS Satellites detect dark matter?

Comment: I don't have full access right now (not on campus), but the abstract & images suggest that a gradient in dark matter content would result in a measurable time lag between two atomic clocks.

Comment: I have to say that this question would be a lot better if you (1) exhibited the abstract here and (2) said a little bit about what you found clear and unclear in the abstract.

Comment: You're right but to be honest am all confused so :Can you just explain how could GPS satellites detect dark matter? Keep it simple.